# Can an Attribute be used more than once in an attribute set?

Tags: magento2, product, attributes

How to reuse an attribute in the same set?  I have a product that has multiple items and I'd like to use **"description"** (attribute) several times.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use same attribute multiple times, you need to create new custom attributes like `description1` `description2` etc and assign to attribute set, but you cannot use same attribute twice with different descriptions.